# Looking for an iPad pencil compatible app with a large or infinite canvas

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, drawing, apple-pencil

I tried Sketch and some other drawing apps. I’d like a bigger canvas to work with. Most seem to only be 8 1/2 by 11 or standard page size.
Is there a way to expand the canvas on some of the basic drawing apps or is the a good app that provides a large drawing area?

Comment: http://www.mybrushes-app.com/MyBrushes-Pro.html

Comment: Same. Like Prezi had. Have not found one yet. Using Paper at the moment, but its frustrating to create new pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- Microsoft OneNote
- Concepts

---

These are best according to me for infinite canvas. Although, OneNote is note-taking but it's OK.

**Concepts** is best one ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Have a close look at [Affinity Designer](https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/designer/).  On the iPad it certainly uses the pencil as an input source, and if its canvas is not actually infinite it is very large and you can zoom in 'infinitely' too.

No, I'm not associated with the company, merely a very happy user of their products.